# Como retornar dados de uma classe dentro de um option

Tags: php, pdo

Boa tarde, pessoal estou com um problema. Sou iniciante em programação orientada a objeto e estou tentando fazer um select/option que recebe valores de dentro do banco de dados em uma tabela funcionário.
O problema é que ao fazer a requisição ao banco por uma classe Select ele me retorna as conexões com o banco, não estou conseguindo retornar os dados e coloca-los dentro de um option.

```
class Select {
private static $conn;

public function __construct() {
    $this->conn = new Conexao();
}

public function Selecionar(){
try{
    $pdo = $this->conn->Conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM funcionario');
    $pdo->execute();
    $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($pdo as $resultado){
        echo $resultado;
        var_dump($resultado);
    }  
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Houver um erro, entrar em contato com administrador.('.$ex->getLine().');window.location.href='/DivinaBeleza/login.php';</script>";
}
}
```

}

e aqui o HTML:

```
                    <select>
                        <option value="1">Chosen</option>
                            <?php
                                $a = new Select();
                                $a->Selecionar();                              
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $result['idFuncionario']; ?>"><?php echo $result['funcaoFuncionario'];?></option>
                    </select>
```

Eu não estou entendendo como dar o return ou passar os dados para a pagina em html criando objetos e instanciando eles. Só então colocar em um option. Pessoal me deem uma luz, faz uns dias que estou tentando e não consegui. Agradeço.
O que aparece para mim é a conexão, se eu uso var_dump ou echo no método selecionar() na variável $resultado, ele me mostra o objeto conexão guardado dentro do array.

Answer (score 0):

ficou bem confusa sua implementação, acho que seria mais fácil você criar a option em outro arquivo e no html você chama esse novo arquivo com as options preenchidas.

```
class Select {
private static $conn;

public function __construct() {
    $this->conn = new Conexao();
}

public function Selecionar(){
try{
    $pdo = $this->conn->Conectar()->prepare('SELECT * FROM funcionario');
    $pdo->execute();
    $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($pdo as $resultado){
            echo $resultado;
        }
}
```

Controller

```
    <?php 
     $select =  new Select();
     $items = $select->Selecionar();
     foreach($items as  item)
     {
       echo '<option value="">'.item['elemento'].// mesmo atributo salvo no banco'</option>'
     }

?>
```

html

```
<select>
    <option value="0" disabled>Escolha um item</option>
      <?php include_once("Controller.php")?>                        
</select>
```